# Save the (String) path to the file located on local HDD

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, jfilechooser, multipartfile

How to save the (String) path to the file or folder located on local HDD using Java/SpringBoot/Thymeleaf? Is it possible at all? I use MultiPartFile to upload selected file, but I can't access the original file path in the controller. I tried JFileChooser also, but it doesn't work when I deploy my app on AWS..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)